# Just learning sparklyr - copy_to() error

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, sparklyr

I know this is a very simple question, and I assume it has been asked before but I have been unable to find it. I would like to learn `sparklyr`. However, I wrote

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr")

install.packages(c("nycflights13", "Lahman"))

library(dplyr)
iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)
```

(from `spark.rstudio.com`) but I get the error:

`Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbDataType’ for signature ‘"spark_connection"’`

I would very much appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: I just ran that code, along with `library(sparklyr)` and `sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")`; it worked fine...

Comment: In my experience with sparklyr, you may need to attempt to re-establish the connection. I have had times where it would take a few tries to get it to work. And sometimes I would get a massive java error dump.

Comment: Btw, after install you did remember to load the library correct?

Comment: Thanks everyone, it worked now. I don't know why, because I did nothing different, but that's fine by me.